# Applying map to multiple 2d arrays in Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, lambda

I'm trying to combine two 2d arrays in Python using map() and a function with an if condition.

When I leave out the if statement, map() works as I'd expect.

This works (but the if condition I need isn't satisfied):

```
list1 = np.array([np.array([1,2,0]),np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([0,0,3])])
list2 = np.array([np.array([4,5,6]),np.array([4,5,6]),np.array([4,5,6])])
collapsed = list(map(lambda x,y:  x + y, list1, list2))
```

And returns:

```
collapsed = [array([5, 7, 6]), array([5, 7, 9]), array([4, 5, 9])]
```

The following returns:

> "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous."

```
collapsed = list(map(lambda x,y:  x + y if x == 0 else x, list1, list2))
```

When what I expected was:

```
collapsed = [[1,2,6][1,2,3][4,5,3]]
```

Comment: Looks like you're adding sublists/arrays there, not integers, hence the error

Comment: True, thanks! Do you know how I would be able to access the individual elements in the arrays without using for loops?

Comment: Can you show us how 2dlist1 and 2dlist to looks like, and the resultant output

Comment: You're saying you're using 2d arrays but doing `x == 0`. If those are 2d arrays, meaning each element in `2dlist1` and `2dlist2` are also arrays. And you're comparing to an int

Comment: Thanks, yeah. How could I compare the individual element within those lists? My issue is that these are very large lists so I need a way to compare relatively quickly.

Comment: And the expected output is what? can you add that, also your example can be run in the second case withoput any errors being thrown if I assume they are normal list of lists, but are they numpy arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
[[list(map(lambda x,y:  x + y if x == 0 else x, a, b))] for a, b in zip(la, lb)]
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked well without a set of brackets, i.e. 
`[list(map(lambda x,y:  x + y if x == 0 else x, a, b)) for a, b in zip(la, lb)]`. 
Do you know how I could make this run faster for large arrays? Are there other methods I should look into?

Comment: @Elias There is another point: you can write `[list(map(lambda x,y: y if x == 0 else x, a, b)) for a, b in zip(la, lb)]` because x + y is y if x == 0.